# How to/Can we hide share target apps(e.g OneNote, Twitter, etc.) that are displayed after tapping share from charms bar using c# in win 8/winrt apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am developing an app in which I am using SetText() method to share string contents from my app via Mail, but I want to restrict from sharing via OneNote, Twitter, etc.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Perhaps, I read on MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465251.aspx#best_practices). They say that- It appears "by default" in the list of share targets each time people share from your app. Does this mean we can not change/chose the list of share target apps? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of restricting what apps can pick up the content you'd like to share. By design sharing through the Share Charm works by bridging data from a ShareSource to a ShareTarget.

As a ShareSource, which your app is in this case, you offer content of a certain type (in this case text). Other apps can offer themselves as a ShareTarget for certain types, so if they list text they will show up. Only the user can hide certain apps through the settings screen.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just wanted to make sure whether it is feasible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want to.
Here is the [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/share-charm-frequently-asked-questions) for the same.

**The procedure is**

The Share charm automatically lists all of the apps installed on your PC that can share. But if you don't want certain apps to appear, you can remove them from the list without uninstalling them.To remove an app from the app list :-

1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings.
   (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.) Then tap or click Share.
2. Under Use these apps to share, find the app you don't want to appear, then set the slider to Off to remove it.

Comment: The above procedure is correct but manual. I want to do the same through coding(c#) in Windows 8 app. I mean whenever user will launch my app and try to share anything, User should only see "Mail" option and not the OneNote, Twitter etc.

Comment: This procedure needs administrative rights which is not provided in WindowsRT Apps.
I was also looking for accessing this kind of administrative rights in WinRT Apps.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done via code in Windows 8. However if you want to just share straight to the mail app I'd recommend using protocols instead.

Something like the following will launch the users default mail app with the specified text etc.

```
public async void SendEmail()
{
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto://nigel.sampson@compiledexperience.com?subject=demo&body=some%20text"));
}
```